# actionDone imeOption doesn't work on EditText in Android 2.3

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a problem using an `EditText` in Android 2.3.

I have an `EditText` defined with `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` property but when I'm writing by the virtual keyboard the return key doesn't detect the `actionDone` and it introduce a return line.

In Android 2.2 is working right.

```
<EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:imeOptions="actionDone" />
```

Comment: It's worth noticing that I've found that implementing a TextWatcher can sometimes have strange effects on the actionDone option.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

I have resolved this issue. I have added the `android:singleLine="true"` property and it works right.

```
<EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:singleLine="true" 
 />
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It works for 

`android:imeOptions="actionNext" 
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/addjob_description"
android:singleLine="true"`

as well.

Comment: Does anyone know why this is working? I'm not complaining, though :)))

Comment: it is a little strange indeed that you need to add also `android:singleLine="true"` so `android:imeOptions="actionSearch"` have an effect...

Comment: I believe it only works when single line is enabled because it uses the same button (at least on my Android).

Comment: Paul, it is so, because in case of a multi-line text, the default ime action is a carriage return. To change it to something else, there should be a single-line text.

Comment: Also note that setting some inputTypes will cause the imeOption to be ignored.  For example, setting the inputType to textShortMessage will give you the smiley faces key even if the imeOption is set to something like actionDone.

Comment: Dang. I want 'Done' on a multi-line text box. Is that not possible?

Comment: `android:singleLine="true"` is deprecated. Use `android:maxLines="1" android:inputType="text"` instead for newer versions.

Comment: and still in December 2016 this is the only way i can get imeOptions working on `inputType="text"`, given that it was deprecated in v3 and we are now in v25 that just seems insane

Answer (score 9):

Another noteworthy point is that the `android:imeOptions` don't work if you specify `android:digits`. Not sure if this affects all android versions.

Comment: Yeah I've noticed that Android decides to overwrite the imeOptions with whatever it decides to put in it... Lol why put it if you're just going to over write it anyways. Another Android annoyance.

Answer (score 1):

Currently in Android Studio 2.2.3 if you use

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

IDE gives a warning that it has been deprecated use maxlines instead.

```
android:maxLines="1"
```

However maxLines does not solve the problem.
The solution is to just add the attribute **inputType**.
Example :

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/actionDoneDemo"
    android:layout_below="@id/nameET"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:hint="Action Done Demo"
    android:inputType="text"/>
```