# Android: How to get a search keyboard in Android 2.2?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a app in which i have edit text. I want to use it as a search bar. So when i click on it, i want to get a keypad in which i should have a search button.

I tried it using:  android:imeOptions="actionSearch", android:imeActionLabel="Search" but i didnt get it. In android 2.1 we are getting it, but in android 2.2 we are not getting it. Can any one you suggest a good solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Its already answered at SO. Check out the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5579944/786337)

Your edittext should be set as singleLine.