# Changing the focus of the edittexts in a list view Using the next Key in SoftKeyBoard

Tags: android

How to configure the next button to change focus to the edit texts in the consecutive rows of the ListView..
I cannot use the android:nextFocusDown="@+id/...." since the edit texts have same id.

Answer (score 0):

try this and let me know If this is what u wanted?

```
 <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

[actionDone imeOption doesn't work on EditText in Android 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578991/actiondone-imeoption-doesnt-work-on-edittext-in-android-2-3)

Comment: Unfortunately that is not what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

To change focus of EditText in rows of ListView you can use following XML example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_1"
        android:nextFocusRight="@+id/edit_2"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_2"
        android:nextFocusRight="@+id/edit_3"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        />

   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_3"
        android:nextFocusRight="@+id/edit_4"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        />

   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_4"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/edit_1"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```