# android:imeOptions. Button not showing up

Tags: android, user-interface, ime

I tried setting `android:imeOptions` to `actionSend`, `actionSearch`. But there's no "Send" or "Search" button on the keyboard, just usual "Enter" key. I also tried setting different input types. (I'm working with HTC Sensation XL.) What's wrong?

Comment: is your EditText has attribute like `android:singleLine="true"`?

Comment: Please, see my comment to the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these [actionDone imeOption doesn't work on EditText in Android 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578991/actiondone-imeoption-doesnt-work-on-edittext-in-android-2-3)

if it is not supported read [How do I handle ImeOptions' done button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004344/android-edittext-imeoptions-done-track-finish-typing). May be the HTC implemented their own soft keyboard which ignores the imeOptions

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, it looks as if HTC doesn't support imeOptions, because it works on ASUS Android tablet.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest switching your `EditText` to `singleLine` mode

Comment: Seems like it doesn't help. [Here's](http://images.devs-on.net/Image/lSHNHCu7vvzCBFrS-.png) all the properties. Could be with/without `lines=1`.

Comment: Yes you are correct but as single line true is deprecated so we have to find some another way

Comment: `singeLine=true` is deprecated in favor of `maxLines=1`

Comment: it works when singleLine=true, and not works when maxLine=1

Comment: I still don't understand, if singleline was deprecated, how it it affecting the IMEOptions?

Answer (score 1):

Currently in Android Studio 2.2.3 if you use

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

IDE gives a warning that it has been deprecated use maxlines instead.

```
android:maxLines="1"
```

However maxLines does not solve the problem. The solution is to just add the attribute inputType. Example :

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/actionDoneDemo"
    android:layout_below="@id/nameET"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:hint="Action Done Demo"
    android:inputType="text"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do in xml:

```
<EditText android:imeOptions="actionSearch" 
    android:inputType="text"/>
```

Happy Coding!!