# Android imeOptions="actionDone" not working

Tags: android, imeoptions

I am trying to get a login screen for an Android app and so far this is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext">

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"  />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonLaunchTriage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/login" />
    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

When I try to run it, the keyboard shows the right keys but when I try to press done after entering the password, nothing happens. I am using this to handle the button press:

```
private void setupLoginButton() {
    Button launchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLaunchTriage);
    launchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.patient_start_userName_value);
            EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.patient_start_password_value);

            try {
                if(TriageApplicationMain.validateUser(username.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString(),getApplicationContext()))
                {
                Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this,
                        "Launching Triage Application", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                startActivity(new Intent(StartActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                }

                else
                     {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            StartActivity.this);


                        // set dialog message
                        alertDialogBuilder
                            .setMessage("Incorrect Credentials")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                    // if this button is clicked, close
                                    // current activity
                                dialog.cancel();    
                                }
                              });


                            // create alert dialog
                            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                            // show it
                            alertDialog.show();

                    }
                }


            catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

I know this is a lot of code, but if anyone could help me here it would be great. This is for a school project.

PS: I have searched through Google for a solid hour before posting this so please don't criticize for not doing that. If you find a link that is useful then please share.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting from "done" in soft-input keyboard? hiding keyboard itself or proceed towards login?

Comment: i have been facing the same issue, you will have to add:
android:imeActionLabel="Done"
android:singleLine="true" 
here is the answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578991/actiondone-imeoption-doesnt-work-on-edittext-in-android-2-3/5579944#5579944

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Just add **`android:inputType="..."`** to your EditText. It will work!! :)

Comment: Black Voodoo magic!

Answer (score 46):

You should set OnEditorActionListener for the EditText to implement the action you want to perform when user clicks the "Done" in keyboard.

Thus, you need to write some code like:

```
password.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            // Do whatever you want here
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

See the tutorial at [android developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html)

Answer (score 25):

Qianqian is correct. Your code only listens for the button click event, not for the EditorAction event.

I want to add that some phone vendors may not properly implement the DONE action. I have tested this with a Lenovo A889 for example, and that phone never sends `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE`when you press done, it always sends `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_UNSPECIFIED` so I actually end up with something like

```
myEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onEditorAction(final TextView v, final int actionId, final KeyEvent event)
  {
    boolean handled=false;

    // Some phones disregard the IME setting option in the xml, instead
    // they send IME_ACTION_UNSPECIFIED so we need to catch that
    if(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE==actionId || EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_UNSPECIFIED==actionId)
    {
      // do things here

      handled=true;
    }

    return handled;
  }
});
```

Also note the "handled" flag (Qianqian didn't explain that part). It might be that other OnEditorActionListeners higher up are listening for events of a different type. If your method returns false, that means you didn't handle this event and it will be passed on to others. If you return true that means you handled/consumed it and it will not be passed on to others.

Comment: Thanks I was exactly getting this IME_ACTION_UNSPECIFIED instead of the expected IME_ACTION_SEND

Answer (score 11):

Use `android:inputType="Yours"` then

```
android:lines="1"
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

Comment: this works. Please note I used `android:singleLine="true"` instead of the `android:lines="1"`

Answer (score 8):

After trying many things, this is what worked for me:

```
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

Comment: Also `android:singleLine="true"` will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

just Add this to your attributes :

```
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

Doc: [here](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style)

Comment: For me android:singleLine="true" made the trick, i guess inputtype=textpassword forces single line true.. which kinda makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You should set OnEditorActionListener for the EditText to implement the action you want to perform when user clicks the "Done" in keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Qianqian & peedee answers:

Here's the reason why the action id is EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_UNSPECIFIED (0) for any enter event.

> actionId
>   int: Identifier of the action. This will be either the identifier you supplied, or EditorInfo#IME_NULL if being called due to the enter key being pressed.

(*Source:* [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener))

So the proper way to handle enter key events would be:

```
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
        // Handle return key here
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in XML

```
android:id="@+id/edittext"
android:maxLines="1"
android:inputType="text"
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

in Java

```java
edittext.setOnEditorActionListener((textView, actionId, keyEvent) - > {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
        /////////////Your Code Here////////////////
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```